# API get cross domain issues - Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB)

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, api, get

I'm trying to use API to get information about a specific user based on user ID. I need to use basic auth and pass some headers with my call. 
I'm getting this:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response  "rest/user/getProfile?callback=jQuery224033348109431646855_1548684613983&userId=24068..." with MIME type text/plain.
```

My code:

```
$.ajax
  ({
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    url: 'example_URL_/api/user/getProfile',
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic ZHVubmVzYXBpskjoi43u5409543o9tI654kjhugjy"); },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: { "Id": "1234" },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(xhr);
      console.log(status);
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
```

is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: You can not set CORS from the javascript code.

Comment: yes, that was me testing, thanks for that...

Comment: Issue you have is trying to make a JSONP call and also trying to set headers. JSONP call uses a script tag, not the XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> ```
> dataType: 'jsonp',
> ```

… so jQuery makes a JSONP request (i.e. inserts a `<script>` element).

The browser makes a request to the URL and the server said:

> ```
> Content-Type: text/plain
> ```

Since a plain text document is not a JavaScript program, the browser refused to execute it and threw a CORB error instead.

A JSONP response must be `application/javascript`, not `text/plain`.

You need to either:

- Not make a request for JSONP
- Change the server to respond with JSONP

---

Aside: Since you are using JSONP, the `type`, `crossDomain`, `async`, `headers`, and `xhr.setRequestHeader` properties have no effect.

Since you said you needed to set basic auth, that rules out option two. You can't use JSONP for this.

Comment: thanks for your response answer. I have no access to the server so I need to do it with javascript. When I change dataType to JSON I'm getting blocked by CORS policy. So I'm trying to get that working somehow

Comment: @Jdoe — the same origin policy is designed to prevent your JavaScript from accessing data that someone else's website is willing to share with the user of the browser. It would be stupid if you would solve this entirely in client-side JS.

Answer (score 1):

In your API configure CORS to accept all domains, or enter the domain that you're using to send the request from.

If your API is created by PHP here is an example:

```php
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Or if you are using a third party API, try to see the documentation. I'm sure there will be a part talking about CORS.

Comment: thanks, it is third party API and I have no access to server setup.